# is there someone who can clarify this error assignment to expression with array type

Tags: c

find my code down

```
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{

    int BT[15]={0};
    int TAT[15]={0};
    int WT[15]={0};
    int P[15]={0};
    int pos=0;
    int i=0;
    int n=0;
    int temp=0;
    int j=0;
    system("clear");
    printf("\nEnter no.of processes:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter P[%d] burst time:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&BT[i]);
        P[i]=i+1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        pos=i;
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(BT[j]<BT[pos])
                pos=j;
        }
        temp=BT[i];
        BT[i]=BT[pos];
        BT[pos]=temp;
        temp=P[i];
        P[i]=P[pos];
        P[pos]=temp;
    }
    WT[0]=0;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        WT[i]=0;
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            WT[i]+=BT[j];
    }
    printf("\nProcess \t BurstTime \t WT \t TAT\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        TAT+=WT[i]+BT[i];
        printf("\nP%d\t\t %d\t\t %d\t\t %d",P[i],BT[i],WT[i],TAT[i]);
    }

}
```

the error is on TAT+=WT[i] + BT[i];
and all my variables are arrays but i don't why i'm getting this error, i tried to manipulated the other variables, to see if i'll find a solution but i did not.
can you please show or help me for this error

Comment: Can it be more clear than the error message itself? You assign to the array `TAT`. That's not possible... did you intend to do `TAT[i]+=WT[i]+BT[i];`

Comment: You cannot assign a value to an array. You can only assign values to the individual elements of an array. The only exception is when declaring the array.